# Redirect Console Output to JavaFX TextArea?

Tags: java, javafx, console, fxml

I want to show the console output in a JavaFX TextArea... unfortunately I cannot find any working example for JavaFX but only for Java Swing, which not seems to work in my case.

**EDIT:**

I tried to follow this example: http://unserializableone.blogspot.ch/2009/01/redirecting-systemout-and-systemerr-to.html

and extended my code as shown below. However, there is no console output anymore in my Eclipse IDE but also no output in my TextArea. Any idea where I am doing wrong?

```
public class Activity extends OutputStream implements Initializable {

@FXML
public static TextArea taRecentActivity;

public Activity() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    OutputStream out = new OutputStream() {
        @Override
        public void write(int b) throws IOException {
            updateTextArea(String.valueOf((char) b));
        }

        @Override
        public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
            updateTextArea(new String(b, off, len));
        }

        @Override
        public void write(byte[] b) throws IOException {
            write(b, 0, b.length);
        }
    };

    System.setOut(new PrintStream(out, true));
    System.setErr(new PrintStream(out, true));
}

private void updateTextArea(final String text) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            taRecentActivity.appendText(text);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void write(int arg0) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to capture System.out and/or System.err, or do you want to capture messages logged via (one of the many) Java Logging APIs?

Comment: Yes, I mean to capture System.out and System.err and then redirect it to the TextArea

Comment: Please explain what "not seems to work in my case" means.  Are you getting an exception?  If you are, please post the entire stack trace of it.  Also, be aware that assuming one byte represents one character will be a problem for text content outside the ASCII range.

Comment: Well, actually there is nothing to show as I simply do not have any  Java Swing Components in my code... So I am wondering how I could show the console output in an JavaFX textarea as I cannot find any useful tutorial.

Comment: I updated my code & linked to a tutorial but still not working. any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just did this and it worked. Though it was very slow with large amounts of text.

```
public void appendText(String str) {
    Platform.runLater(() -> textField.appendText(str));
}
```

and

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    OutputStream out = new OutputStream() {
        @Override
        public void write(int b) throws IOException {
            appendText(String.valueOf((char) b));
        }
    };
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(out, true));
}
```

Comment: yes, it is a little bit slow but more than okay - works great! really appreciate your input!

Comment: Just a question on that... i am using your solution for appending console to a textarea, however my netbeans console is not updated any more! Is there any way to have both (netbeans console & textarea) being updated?

Comment: @thanili In the first line of `initialize()`, cache the current standard output stream: `PrintStream defaultOut = System.out;`. Then in the `write(int b)` method add the line `defaultOut.write(b);`.

Comment: Hi, it doesn't work well with UTF-8, is there a solution for that ?