# How to show println in Label Javafx

Tags: java, javafx

```
// init the file objects and the initial drive state
public class UsbDetector
for ( int i = 0; i < letters.length; ++i )
    {
    usb[i] = new File(letters[i]+":/");

    isDrive[i] = usb[i].canRead();
    }

 System.out.println("waiting for USB...");

 // loop indefinitely
 while(true)
    {
    // check each drive 
    for ( int i = 0; i < letters.length; ++i )
        {
        boolean pluggedIn = usb[i].canRead();

        // if the state has changed output a message
        if ( pluggedIn != isDrive[i] )
            {
            if ( pluggedIn )
                System.out.println("Drive "+letters[i]+" has been inserted");
            else
                System.out.println("Drive "+letters[i]+" has been removed");

            isDrive[i] = pluggedIn;
            };
```

Comment: Hopefully `while(true)` has its own thread. If not, you will run into problems.

Comment: There probably are ```breaks``` in the portion of code we can't see.  Hopefully**

Comment: what is the problem, exactly? Anyway, please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates what's not behaving as you expect it to behave.

Comment: It's unclear what exactly you're asking about here. You need to clarify what you're trying to achieve and how the code fails to accomplish that. (Code that could be compiled/part of compilable code would be preferred though btw.) Possibly this could be done with an approach like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26961603/2991525 (Not sure this is what you're asking about though...)

Answer (score 0):

*How to show println in Label Javafx*

```
Label label = new Label(yourText);
```

or

```
label.setText(yourText);
```